# Enable Streamed Video Skipping Using PHP & Curl

Tags: php, html, curl, video, video-streaming

I'm using the following code:

```
class SplitCurlByLines {

    public function curlCallback($curl, $data) {

        $this->currentLine .= $data;
        $lines = explode("\n", $this->currentLine);
        // The last line could be unfinished. We should not
        // proccess it yet.
        $numLines = count($lines) - 1;
        $this->currentLine = $lines[$numLines]; // Save for the next callback.

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numLines; ++$i) {
            $this->processLine($lines[$i]); // Do whatever you want
            ++$this->totalLineCount; // Statistics.
            $this->totalLength += strlen($lines[$i]) + 1;
        }
        return strlen($data); // Ask curl for more data (!= value will stop).

    }

    public function processLine($str) {
        // Do what ever you want (split CSV, ...).
        echo $str . "\n";
    }

    public $currentLine = '';
    public $totalLineCount = 0;
    public $totalLength = 0;

} // SplitCurlByLines

$splitter = new SplitCurlByLines();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array($splitter, 'curlCallback') );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 0'
));
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . $response['download_content_length']);
header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $response['download_content_length']);
$splitter->processLine($splitter->currentLine);
curl_close ( $ch );
```

to stream an MP4 video **grabbed from another website**, but after I use HTML5 video, it doesn't allow me to skip time, so how can I do that?

I'm using PHP7 and Apache2.

Comment: do you have the full video downloaded, including the MOOV atom which provides the metadata about how times and byte-ranges are mapped?

Comment: do you have the full video downloaded : No , i don't download it , it's coming from an external url (Google Drive DIrect link)

Comment: so, without the MOOV atom the browser won't know what byte range request to request if you skip ahead. Can you try re-encoding the video (eg using ffmpeg and the -faststart parameter) to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: ok , but i'd like to stream the video directly to the user , so if i use ffmpeg i'll have many problems as he'll have to wait for the video to be processed , is there another way?

Comment: depending on how big the video is, you could load the whole thing into a blob and then display that

Comment: @Offbeatmammal the videos' sizes are between 300-2048 Mb , so.. i think it won't work :(